# Correct jQuery for replacing content within a <span> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`$(document).ready( $("#machType").each(function() {$(this).replace('machine1 (windows)', 'Windows Machine 1');})); ";`
Is that snippet above correct for changing the content of a span? (enclosed in  tags of course)

Assuming I have the `machType`'s

```
<span id="machType">Machine 1 (windows)</span></span id="machType">Machine 2 (windows)
```

Comment: ID's need to be unique. Change those to `<span class="machType">`

Comment: I take it I can just use .machType as a selector?

Comment: yesm use .somthing as selector. Besides what stops u from testing this? Does not look like something that will blow up anything.

Comment: Unfortunately the environment that this sits on is needlessly complex. Doesnt seem to like my code for changing each span with a class of "machType"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should help (give each `span` a `class` of `machType`):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".machType").each(function () {
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/Machine (\d+) \((.*)\)/, function (full, num, os) {
            return [os[0].toUpperCase(), os.substring(1), " Machine ", num].join("");
        }));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready( 
    $(".machType").each(function(index, value) {
        $(value).html($(value).html().replace('machine1 (windows)', 'Windows Machine 1'));
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( $("#machType").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('machine1 (windows)', 'Windows Machine 1');
}));
```